# How fast can I compare an array of images?

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

Consider an image(`image`) as

[image]

Let's now split the image into several parts.

```
n=4;
imageparts = ImagePartition[image, ImageDimensions[image]/n];
len = Length@imageparts;
```

Now I would like to compare each part with the rest.

```
Table[ImageDistance[imageparts[[i, j]], imageparts[[k, l]]], {i, 1, 
  len}, {j, 1, len}, {k, 1, len}, {l, 1, len}]
```

This is a very slow and redundant approach. It compares each part with itself and the same two parts is compared twice (that's why redundant). Moreover, the technique iterates over the length `4` times.

How can I improve the speed while having the information about which two parts are compared to get the corresponding distance?

[Note: I have chosen the value of `n` as `4` just for illustration purpose. The actual value of `n` can be much larger and the real complexity arises then.]

Answer (score 5):

The function that you are looking for is called `DistanceMatrix`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6RvB.png"];
parts = ImagePartition[img, ImageDimensions[img]/n];
dm = DistanceMatrix[Flatten[parts]];
```

The following gets the comparison between image `(i1, j1)` and `(i2, j2)` in the original matrix given by `ImagePartition`:

```
Part[dm, (i1 - 1) n + j1, (i2 - 1) n + j2]
```

where `dm` is the distance matrix and `n` is the number of columns in the original matrix.

A distance function can be specified in the following way:

```
df = ImageDistance[#, #2, DistanceFunction -> "MeanEuclideanDistance"] &;
DistanceMatrix[Flatten[parts], DistanceFunction -> df];
```

Comment: In this result, please, where is the comparison between the subimage {1,3} and the one {2,2}?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Thank you for pointing this out; that comparison was not included in the original answer, but I've fixed it now.

Comment: Wow, even quite, quite faster than my approach, +1...

Comment: @C.E. Can I set the `DistanceFunction` as `MeanEuclideanDistance`?

Comment: @Majis I added an example of that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is `Subsets`. However, you can implement this with `Table` as well. Something like this should work:

```
distance[{{i_, j_}, {k_, l_}}] := ImageDistance[imageparts[[i, j]], imageparts[[k, l]]];

With[{pos = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, len}, {j, len}], 1]},
 {distance[#], #} & /@ Subsets[pos, {2}]
]
```

This gives you the 120 distances with the information which image-parts were compared.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should create all the combinations avoiding to calculate `ImageDistance` of the image with itself, and twice for two images, as noted by OP. Thus :

```
n=4;
comparisons = Cases[Union[Tuples[Range[n], {2, 2}], 
                    SameTest -> ((Reverse[#1] == #2) &)], {a_, b_} /; a != b]
```

Then, we can valuate the `ImageDistance` of all comparisons:

```
ImageDistance[Part[imageparts, #[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]], 
              Part[imageparts, #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]] & /@ comparisons
```

While the last calculation can be fast, it depends on the number of subimages. Bear in mind that creating the comparisons becomes sloppy when $n$ increases (in my old Intel I3 processor).

Answer (score -1):

Use flatten arrays `[[i*n+j]]` and `[[k*n+l]]` instead of double indices and compare only if `k*n+l>i*n+j`. And use parallel table.

Comment: That is a valid tip, quite minimal though. Could you provide full code / timings with ExampleData images for example?